# Basic transportation problem to Aggregated Uncapacitated Network Design Problem

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I am doing a practice with `Python Pulp` to solve some transportation problem.

I habe been able to solve a basic beer transportation problem with this code:

```
import pulp as lp


model=lp.LpProblem('Modelo de localización',lp.LpMinimize)


fabricas=['A','B']
cap_fabricas={'A':1500,'B':1500}
tiendas=['1','2','3']
cap_tiendas={'1':1000,'2':1000,'3':1000}

rutas=[(i,j) for i in fabricas for j in tiendas]
dict_costes={'A':dict(zip(tiendas,[23,20,45])),'B':dict(zip(tiendas,[21,34,11]))}

x_ij=lp.LpVariable.dicts('rutas',(fabricas,tiendas),lowBound=0,cat=lp.LpInteger)
model+=lp.lpSum([x_ij[i][j]* dict_costes[i][j] for i in fabricas for j in tiendas]),'COSTES DE TRANSPORTE'
for i in fabricas:
    model+=lp.lpSum([x_ij[i][j] for j in tiendas])<=cap_fabricas[i]
for j in tiendas: 
    model+=lp.lpSum([x_ij[i][j] for i in fabricas])>=cap_tiendas[j]

model.solve(solver)


print('Solution status:',lp.LpStatus[model.status])
for v in model.variables():
    print('Quantity from:',v.name,' is',v.varValue(),'ud')
print('Cost is:',lp.value(model.objective),'€')
```

Now I have to solve an `Uncapacitated Network Design Problem` but in version `aggregate`.

The problem definition is such as the basic transportation problem, but just one source, and two warehouses. In the middle there is one medium warehouse.

Visually the schema is like this:

[image]

But i dont know how to add this in the model. I guess that is something like source quantity, should be equal to medium warehouse quantity, and equal to destiny warehouses.

Any idea of how to add this into the model?

Comment: I don't understand the graph.What do the numbers (and numbers in brackets) represent? What is the objective?

Comment: @kabdulla the goal is to minimize the total cost.
The number in brackets are variable costs, which is for each unit send throught that arc.
And the number outside the brackets are fix costs. Which are applied if the arc is used (binary)

The goal is to send two products from 1, to 3 and 4. (One to each node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running:

```
import pulp as lp

# Model Data
nodes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
routes = [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,4), (1,4)]
fixed_costs = {(1,2):5, (2,3):25, (3,4):20, (2,4):15, (1,4):10}
var_costs = {(1,2):5, (2,3):5, (3,4):5, (2,4):5, (1,4):30}
demand = {1:0, 2:0, 3:1, 4:1}
source_capacity = {1:sum(demand.values()), 2:0, 3:0, 4:0}

# Declare Problem
model=lp.LpProblem('network opt',lp.LpMinimize)

# Are routes open?
rt_open = lp.LpVariable.dicts('rt_open',routes,lowBound=0,cat=lp.LpBinary)

# Flow along routes:
flow = lp.LpVariable.dicts('flow',routes,lowBound=0,cat=lp.LpInteger)

# units sourced at each node
source = lp.LpVariable.dicts('source',nodes,lowBound=0,cat=lp.LpInteger)

# Objective
model += lp.lpSum([fixed_costs[r]*rt_open[r] + var_costs[r]*flow[r] for r in routes])

# Constraints
for i in nodes:
    # Constrains on sourcing:
    model += source[i] <= source_capacity[i]

    # Constraint on flow: source + flow in = demand + flow out
    model += source[i] + lp.lpSum([flow[r] for r in routes if r[1] == i]) == \
                                demand[i] + lp.lpSum([flow[r] for r in routes if r[0] == i])

for r in routes:
    # Flow can only go along open routes
    model += flow[r] <= rt_open[r]*sum(demand.values())

# Solve problem & print results
model.solve()
print('Solution status:',lp.LpStatus[model.status])

for v in model.variables():
    print(v.name,': ',v.varValue)

print('Cost is:',lp.value(model.objective))
```

Returns:

```
flow_(1,_2) :  2.0
flow_(1,_4) :  0.0
flow_(2,_3) :  1.0
flow_(2,_4) :  1.0
flow_(3,_4) :  0.0
rt_open_(1,_2) :  1.0
rt_open_(1,_4) :  0.0
rt_open_(2,_3) :  1.0
rt_open_(2,_4) :  1.0
rt_open_(3,_4) :  0.0
source_1 :  2.0
source_2 :  0.0
source_3 :  0.0
source_4 :  0.0
Cost is: 65.0
```